# how to track in real time created markers from firebase in maps api javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

i can display the markers created from lat and lon values from firebase but they don't change the current location unless i reload the page, i need to know how to track the markers created in real time without reloading the page, so this is the code that obtains and creates the markers from firebase, it's not all the code but i thinks its all i need to show.

```
firebase.database().ref('reference').once('value',(data)=>{
                    data.forEach(function(snapshot){
                        var newPost = snapshot.val();
                        var NLat = parseFloat(newPost.Latitud);
                        var NLon = parseFloat(newPost.Longitud);
                        var ubicacion = new google.maps.LatLng(NLat, NLon);
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: myLatlng,
                            draggable: true
                        });

                        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: 'icon.png',
                            position: locat,
                            draggable: true,
                            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10), 
                            labelClass: "label" 
                        });
                        marker2.addListener('click', function() {
                            infowindow.open(map, marker2);
                        });

                    });
                });


            }
```

Comment: Why are you using `.once` if you want the markers to update?

Comment: it's wrong? i changed it for .on and now works but it creates a lot of marker where i walk

Comment: Then remove the old markers before adding new ones

Comment: like this? :                                                                                                             if (marker && marker.setMap) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  }

Comment: Looks right, but hard to tell given the information posted.